# laravel how to make a column filter in the blade header

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-filters

I am working on a laravel project, I wanna load the datatable and make a filter on the header, I have 3 column in the header, can I click one header column with a calender pop up and I can choose a date as a request.
I currently can make a filter when the filter column list is provided.

here is the controller:

```
$filter = ["Col1" => [1,2,3]];
```

here is the markup:

```
    <x-thead :headers="Constants::FUNDER_NOTE" :filter="$filter"></x-thead>
```

here is the script:

```
var datatable = $('#mytable').on('xhr.dt', function(e, settings, json, xhr) {
            $("#loadingAnimation").hide();
        }).DataTable({
ajax: {
        url: "/xxxxxx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        columns: [],
            },
initComplete: function(settings, json) {
                this.api()
                    .column(1)
                    .every(function() {
                        var column = this;
                        var select = $("[name='Col1']")
                            .on('change', function() {
                                var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
                                var text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
                                console.log(val, text);
                                column.search('db_col_1', val ? val : false, false).draw();
                            });
                    });
});
```

here is my api to receive the UI request:

```
$filter = $request->db_col_1 ?? 'no result';
```

in this way I can get the $filter variable to know db_col_1 is need to be filtered with the selected value ($filter), but I have to provide the db_col_1 content in advance, i need to make another filter about the date, can I just click that header column and a calender popup window appears and make the filter as the above method? can you please help me to figure it out? MANY THANKS!

Comment: Is your server-side receiving all the filters you want?

Comment: @LajosArpad yes

Comment: Can you show a sample of the filter values on your server-side?